# can a Map also be a Collection?

Tags: java, collections, jstl

I'd like to have a Map that is also a Collection.  Or more specifically, I'd like to be able to iterate over the entries in a Map, including the case where there are multiple entries for a particular key.

The specific problem I'm trying to solve is providing an object that can be used in jstl both to iterate over using `c:forEach` and in an expression like `${a.b.c}`.  In this example, I'd want `${a.b.c}` to evaluate to the the first value of `c` (or null if there are none), but also be able to iterate over all `c`s with `<c:forEach items="${a.b.c}">` and have the loop body see each individual value of `c` in turn, although they have the same key in the Map.

Looking at things from a method point of view, this should be straightforward, just provide a `Map` implementation whose `entrySet()` method returns a set with multiple Entries with the same key.  But since this seems to violate the contract of a Map, will things break in subtle yet disastrous ways?  Has anyone else done this sort of thing?

(If you guessed I'm trying to present xml, you'd be correct)

*EDIT*

Please note that this is for use in jstl, so whatever interface I present must meet 2 conditions:

- for use with the `[]` and `.` operators, it must be a `Map`, `List`, array or JavaBeans object (and of those it can't be a List or array because the indexes will not be numbers)
- for use with forEach it must be an array, `Collection`, `Iterator`, `Enumeration`, `Map`, or `String`.

So I guess the real question is, can I count on jstl *only* calling `.containsKey()`, `.get()`, and `.entrySet()` and not caring about invariants being violated, and not internally making a copy of the Map which would not preserve the special iteration behavior.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is a [Multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap). [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) provides an implementation of it and specifically you are looking for [ArrayListMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html).

Comment: Close, but that doesn't look like exactly what I need.  I don't want the `get()` method to return a list of all the values, I want it to return some single well-defined value (i.e., the first value).  It also doesn't appear to be a `Map`, so I can't use it without modification in jstl EL.

Answer (score 0):

I barely remember jstl, but what you're saying sounds a kind of controversial:
In foreach:

here ${a.b.c} should point to some container of values and then we iterate over it.

On the other hand you say, ${a.b.c} "should evaluate to the the first value of c" (or null...)
Its an ambiguous definition.

If you feel like Multimap is not what you want, you can provide your own collection implementation (probably internally based on Multimap)

Just as an idea you can always look at a single element as a list (that accidentally 
is comprised of one element). This way you would resolve your ambiguity, I guess.

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes, the expression is ambiguous, with different meanings depending on the context.  But I can make it unambiguous in an implementation by saying that the string value will be exactly the first value.  This whole problem is coming from trying to make the best (meaning well defined and not an exception;  correctness isn't possible for obvious reasons) of an ambiguous situation.

Answer (score 0):

Having a `Map` with multiple entries for the same key irreparably breaks the `Map`  contract.  If `Multimap` doesn't work for you, then there's no way to do this without breaking a lot of things.

Specifically, if you pass your monstrosity to something that's specified to take a `Map`, it'll almost certainly break...and it sounds like that's what you want to do with it, so yeah.

Comment: Will it tho?  It doesn't meet the contract, but the only invariant I can think of that it actually violates is ∀x ∈ Map.entrySet x.getValue == Map.get(x.getKey) and if that isn't verified, then who cares?

Comment: You'll break the identity that keySet().size() == entrySet().size().  But the invariant you already mention is actually a pretty common assumption in code I write that takes Map arguments -- and if you broke it, there's no way of knowing all the stuff that would go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

how about you use a Map with Collections as values? then you can have different values for the same key and you can iterate over them by a nested foreach-loop

you can also easily write a wrapper for an existing map-implementation, which gives you a single iterator over all values, if you need it that way